# How can I create Zend Form Element extends A html tag not INPUT

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element

How can I create Zend Form Element implements A html tag not INPUT. I need create something like that:

```
$Link = new Zend_Form_Element_Link(
    $field_name,
    array( 'label'=>'THIS IS LINK', 'href'="#", 'other_attrs' => array() )
);
```

Do I should use loadDefaultDecorators function or either?

This Link element is not actually related to the Form, it's just simple link to be rendered in Zend Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this series of articles by Matthew Weier O'Phinney:

- [The simplest Zend Form Decorator](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/212-The-simplest-Zend_Form-decorator.html)
- [How to layer Decorators](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/213-From-the-inside-out-How-to-layer-decorators.html)
- [Rendering Zend Form Decorators individually](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/215-Rendering-Zend_Form-decorators-individually.html)
- [Creating composite elements](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/217-Creating-composite-elements.html)

Last one should be of particular interest.